# Problems installing openEMM on Centos 6 running Plesk 11

Tags: mysql, linux, ssh, passwords, centos

I am trying to install openEMM on a Centos 6 VDS and have run into a snag. I am following the instructions on this page: http://www.roothelp.net/install-openemm-on-centos-6-x/. Everything has gone along fine until I reached the following commands:

```
service mysqld start

/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation

cd /usr/share/doc/OpenEMM-2013/

mysqladmin -u root -p create openemm
```

The service starts fine, but when I run /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation I get the following:

> In order to log into MySQL to secure it, we'll need the current
>   password for the root user.  If you've just installed MySQL, and you
>   haven't set the root password yet, the password will be blank, so you
>   should just press enter here.
>
> Enter current password for root (enter for none):

This is where the problems start. Apparently Plesk 11 does not create a root user account, using "admin" instead. None of my passwords work here, neither my actual SSH root password, my admin password, or any other password I've assigned. I even started mysql with this script to ensure I had the correct root password:

```
>UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass') WHERE User='root';
>FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I tried this to ensure I had the correct password: /usr/local/psa/bin/admin --show-password

None of this has worked, and I am unable to run the command. How can I get around this? If I skip that command (GoDaddy support advised me that it was only configuring MySql, which is already installed with Plesk) and try to run

```
mysqladmin -u root -p create openemm
```

I am again asked for a root password and none work. I also tried this command instead, using the admin password but still had the same problem.

```
mysqladmin -u admin -p create openemm
```

I suspect I'll have to create a database called openemm through Plesk. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't set the mysql root password you can set it through the command

```
`$> mysqladmin -u root password "yourpassword"`
```

and if you want to change (or update) a root password, then you need to use the following command:

```
$> mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpass
```

Then you can create your database. In your case I think the mysql root password is just entered as the secure script asked you.

Comment: Apparently Plesk does not create a root account -- rather it uses the admin account, which doesn't work as stated above.